# Swift -Firebase is it possible to Post and Observe at same time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I want to `observe` I run:

```
let likesRef = Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId)
likesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{ (snapshot) in

    let likes = snapshot.childrenCount

    let totalLikes = Int(likes)

    // display totalLikes
})
```

When I want to post I run:

```
let dict = [uid: 1]
let likesRef = Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId)
likesRef.updateChildValues(dict) { [weak self](error, ref) in
    if let error = error { return }
    // if no error then update the ref 
})
```

When posting the `completionBlock` has 2 values:

```
withCompletionBlock: (Error?, DatabaseReference)
```

Is there a way that I can also `observe` the ref that I am posting to using the 2nd `completionBlock` value: `DatabaseReference`:

For eg once the user likes something I want to update the ref and display the new number of likes at the same time without having to run `observeSingleEvent`:

```
let dict = [uid: 1]
let likesRef = Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId)
likesRef.updateChildValues(dict) { (error, ref) in

    if let error = error { return }

    // *** somehow get the total amount of likes from the ref *** 

    // If possible I want to avoid this code below
    likesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{ (snapshot) in

        let likes = snapshot.childrenCount

        let totalLikes = Int(likes)

        // display totalLikes
     })
})
```

Comment: There's an accepted answer but here's the issue. What you're essentially trying to do is track the number of children in a node. As is, that's done by reading in the entire node (which could be thousands of votes) and using .childrenCount. That will result in reading in a LOT of unnecessary data and driving up costs. A better solution is to create a separate *child_count* node with a .childChanged or .value (but not both) observer. When a vote is added to the likes node, increment the child *count_node* by 1. Whenever it's updated, your app will be notified and you can update your UI.

Comment: @Jay what is the difference between *observing* the likes node and the likesCount node. Why is one better then the other when in both situations they still have the same amount of children

Comment: @Jay oh I understand now, the likeCount node only has 1 child which is the total number of likes. Everytime a like is added that count_node just gets 1 added to it and when subtracted it gets 1 subtracted from it. Interesting. Seems like **runTransactionBlock** would be better for the likesCount node

Comment: yes! Absolutely correct. This is the perfect use case for [Transaction Blocks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) as its the solution when working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications such as incremental counters. It seems like you are on the right track here so write some code and let me know if you get stuck and I can craft an example if needed.

Comment: @Jay I'll add something in about an hour or so. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jay I added the code as an answer, can you let me know if it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some very abbreviated code to accomplish the task of adding a users uid who likes a post and incrementing a counter via runTransactionBlock. Keep in mind there are 100 ways to do this.

A proposed structure

```
all_posts
   post_0
      like_count: 2
      post: "Hello, World"

likes
   post_0
      uid_0: true
      uid_1: true
```

Based on the question and discussion, I broke the posts and likes into separate nodes. The reasoning is that when the posts are loaded, they will probably be displayed in a list and all that's really needed at that point is the post topic and the total number of likes, so I made 'like_count' part of the post node.

If we added the actual likes within the post node itself, it could be 10,000 or 10,000,000 and there's no reason to load all of that data when loading in the posts. Having that many likes could also overwhelm the device.

Within the likes node, each post key references the post in the all_posts node. The children are the uid's of the users that liked the post and the value is a boolean 'true' as a placeholder. Nodes with no values cannot exist so 'true' keeps it in place and is a tiny amount of data.

Then the code -

```
func updatePostWithLikesViaTransaction() {
    let postsRef = self.ref.child("all_posts") //self.ref points to my Firebase
    let thisPostRef = postsRef.child("post_0")

    thisPostRef.runTransactionBlock ({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
        if var data = currentData.value as? [String: Any] {
            var count = data["like_count"] as? Int ?? 0
            count += 1
            data["like_count"] = count
            currentData.value = data
        }

      return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print("successfully incremented counter")
        let likesRef = self.ref.child("likes")
        let likesPostRef = likesRef.child(thisPostRef.key!)
        likesPostRef.child("uid_2").setValue(true)
    }
}
```

The above is not ideal by any means but demonstrates the process (and works with the presented structure).

First we get a reference to the post we want to update and then within a transaction block read the currentData 'like_count' child which would return 2 based on the values in the structure. That's incremented to 3, updated within currentData and then updated via the TransactionResult.

runTransactionBlock also has an optional completion callback and we are using that to, upon success, update the post within the likes with the users uid and true.

The end result of running this is that the counter is incremeted to 3 and 'uid_2: true' is added to the 'likes/post_0' node

Answer (score 1):

Actually its not possible to get both Event at same time. Once you like once your data reach at firebase database then you will get Value,Change,ChieldAdded event on App side. It will take 1-2 second or less depend on Internet. So Post will call first and then observer will call.

You can get observer this by two ways:

Step 1 : Add Child Change listener

```
let likesRef = Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId)
likesRef.observe(.childChanged, with: {
        (snapshot) in

    let likes = snapshot.childrenCount

    let totalLikes = Double(Int(likes))

    // display likes
 })
```

Child change listener listens changes on snapshot

Step 2 : Put value listener

```
let likesRef = Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId)
likesRef.observe(.value, with: {
        (snapshot) in

    let likes = snapshot.childrenCount

    let totalLikes = Double(Int(likes))

    // display likes
 })
```

Value listener listens every time

I Hope this will help...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was actually looking to see if there was a way to get it specifically from that ref value without any observation whatsoever. This is the right way to do it but this wasn't the answer I was looking for. Gimme a couple of hours, if no one posts anything about what I was specifically trying to do I'll upvote your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @LanceSamaria Actually its not possible to get both Event at same time. Once you like once your data reach at firebase database then you will get Value,Change,ChieldAdded event on App side. It will take 1-2 second or less depend on Internet. So Post will call first and then observer will call.

Comment: @LanceSamaria I know there's an accepted answer but I am not sure it's correct for this use case. Additionally adding a .childChanged as well as a .value event listener is not needed and will *both* be called (increasing your cost) when a child changes. Also, the code in the answer will load the *entire post* every time a change of any kind occurs to *any* child node - that's a lot of unnecessary data.

Comment: @Jay I was under the assumption that she/he was saying to use either or. I wouldn’t use both. I didn’t know it would load anytime a change to anything occurs. Now that I look at it that makes sense. Can you add an updated answer? I will switch it to yours. I can’t undo the accepted answer (too late) unless there is a better one.

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology read the comments that Jay made. He said your answer will result in enormous costs