# Swift -Firebase Looping Costs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question isn't about how to loop over children, it's about looping over children in different ways to save costs

My database is:

```
-someRef
   -someUserId // say this ref has 10000 children
        -uid1: someVal
        -uid2: someVal
        -uid3: someVal
        ...
        -uid7989: someVal
        ...
        -uid10000: someVal
```

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55319514/4833705) I can loop over children like so:

```
var lookForThisUserId = "uid7989"

someRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

    if snap.key == self.lookForThisUserId {
       // user found
       break
    }
  }
})
```

But I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60653860/4833705) the other day and initially picked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655405/4833705) which turned out to be an inefficient way of trying to do what I wanted done. In the comments @Jay said

> "There's an accepted answer but here's the issue. What you're
>   essentially trying to do is track the number of children in a node. As
>   is, that's done by reading in the entire node (which could be
>   thousands of votes) and using .childrenCount. That will result in
>   reading in a LOT of unnecessary data and driving up costs"

So it got me to thinking, is there any difference **in costs** between the loop code I added above and this code below:

```
var lookForThisUserId = "uid7989"

someRef?.child(lookForThisUserId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() {
        // this user isn't in here
    }

    // user found
})
```

Comment: Why don't you try to benchmark both solutions?
Afaik, firebase works with something like a dict hash right? if you look for a key, the cost won't be that match as it will gets you the value for the given key, without going through the entire dictionary.

Comment: @AlejandroL.Rocha hi, what do you mean by benchmark?

Comment: Measure the performance of the loops

Comment: how would measuring the performance of the loops help me to determine if the first block of code costs more then then second block of code

Comment: I have answered somehting similar in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661612/is-there-a-way-to-measure-swifts-performance-without-building-ui-on-iphone-with/60666707#60666707

Comment: @AlejandroL.Rocha hey thanks for the comments and link. At the moment I'm actually not concerned with which performs better, I'm concerned with which saves more money. But from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658710/4833705 it looks like **someRef?.child(lookForThisUserId)** will be the best way to save in costs

Comment: Might be I am not use to work with firebase at all and I have no idea about the costs in performance for calls in Firebase, but afaik firebase only charges you for amount of network calls and data trasnfers right? 
So I think if you are searching for something in a record of 1000 instead of download all data, you should try to do the search func in their side.

Comment: @AlejandroL.Rocha the second way circumvents the heavy download transfer. Thanks for the advice!